# Verify empty field Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to check if a text field is empty and I can't convert bool to string. 
I am trying this:

```
var firstName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("name_3_firstname"));
if (firstName.Equals(" ")) {
                Console.WriteLine("This field can not be empty");
            }
```

Also, how can I check if certain number field is exactly 20 digits?
Can you help me do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If it's string, then you can use `string.Empty` or `""`, because `" "` contains a space, therefore it's not empty.

For those 20 digits, you can use a bit of a workaround `field.ToString().Length == 20` or you can repetitively divide it by 10 until the resulting value is 0, but I'd say the workaround might be easier to use.

This is more of a general C# answer. I'm not exactly sure how well it's gonna work in Selenium, but I've checked and string.Empty and ToString() appear to exist there.

Answer (score 2):

For Empty / White space / Null, use following APIs of the `string` class

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)` or
`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)`

For exact 20 digits, best is to use the Regular expression as follows, this can also be converted to range and combination of digits and characters if required. Current regular expression ensures that beginning, end and all components are digits

```
string pattern = @"^\d{20}$";
var booleanResult  = Regex.Match(value,pattern).Success
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this way will work in your case. Code:

```
var firstName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("name_3_firstname"));
```

will return to You `IWebElement` object. First you should try to get text of this element. Try something like `firstName.Text`  or `firstName.getAttribute("value");`. When u will have this you will able to check 
:

```
var text = firstName.getAttribute("value");
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)){ // do something }
if(text.length == 20) {// do something}
```